# CSS mat-select cant feel the button

Tags: html, css, angular

When I click on it, the button not work until I click somewhere. How can I give the button a privilege, that mouse can feel it when opened the mat-select

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-placeholder>Search reports</mat-placeholder>
      <mat-select #mySelect>
      <mat-option>Cat</mat-option>
      <mat-option>Dog</mat-option>
      <mat-option>Bird</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
      <button mat-buttons matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="add" (click)="mySelect.close(); alert('open a dialog')"> My Button Not Work
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here the button is active when I hold my mouse cursor over it

[image]

In this situation, I cant click the button, until I don't close the mat-select
[image]

[Here the link where you can test it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tu9xgb?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

This is opinionated solution by material design. You cannot change this behavior.

You can use `<select>` with `matNativeControl` which preserves the native browser behavior in which you can interact with the page on the first click.

```
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I find another way to use it, with #matmat I closing the mat select when the mouse out of the box